# Spring Security with JSON does not work

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-security

I'm brand new to spring and I'm trying to figure out how to authenticate a user.

Currently, it looks like everything is set up correctly. When I use `x-www-form-urlencoded`, I can successfully log in. When using `application/json`, my application does not receive the `emailAddress` parameter.

I have been googling and checking SO, but I can't find anything related.

Here is my `SecurityConfig`.

```
package com.myapp.config;

import com.myapp.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        builder.authenticationProvider(this.authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http.csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("emailAddress").passwordParameter("password")
            .successHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .logout();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you sending your credentials when using `application/json`? What is the code for login form?

Comment: I'm simply using postman. I get a 200 OK when using urlencoded, 401 when using json.

Comment: Yes but what is the code? Does you code convert the form data to valid json string when using `application/json`?

Comment: Except for the detailsService, this is literally it. There is no controller or anything in front of this. I didn't think you needed anything else?

Comment: And also if you want to send json string instead of the post parameters then you need custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` implementation to parse json string from `HttpRequest`.

Comment: Do you have a login form? If not how are you even obtaining the credentials in the first place?

Comment: It's supposed to be a REST api. So no, no traditional login form. Just the /login endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

```
formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("emailAddress").passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
```

In the above configure, a standard `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is used to obtain username and password from request parameter. However, the standard filter do not parse parameters from your json string in the request.

You may try to create a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to obtain username and password from the your json string and apply your custom filter in configuration. However, unlike XML configuration that can use `<custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="yourCustomFilter" />`, you cannot replace the form login filter with your custom filter by Java Config.

As a workaround, you can try with follows:

1. Create a custom filter extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to obtain the username and password from json string and put the parsed parameters into the request. The solution is to use `HttpRequestWrapper` class, which allow you to wrap one request with another. You can subclass that, and override the `getParameter` to return username and password which is parsed from json string. You can then pass the wrapped request to `chain.doFilter`.
2. Add the custom filter before the standard `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` with `HttpSecurity#addFilterBefore(yourCustomFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)`

As the username and password is parsed from json string to the request parameter, the standard `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` should be able to perform authentication.